# Is there a way to import data from Dynamic 365 into my SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

We have Dynamic 365 in the company. Is there any way to import the data from D365 into my SQL Server database through SSIS, not a third party tool?

Comment: If *you* don't have access to the database, then how are you going to access said data to copy it? Sounds like you don't have access for a reason, and so shouldn't be trying to copy it.

Comment: Dynamics365 has an extensive REST API - but that's about as close as you get to the actual data. There's also a new [SQL endpoint ontop of the Common Data Service](https://markcarrington.dev/2020/05/13/cds-t-sql-endpoint-pt-1-connecting/)  - maybe that'll be of help?

Comment: Is it Dynamics 365 or is it on-premises dynamics? Please be specific otherwise no one will be able to help. If it's Dynamics 365 then you can easily use Azure Data Factory to copy the data into SQL.

Comment: If it's Dynamics 365 there's also a built in tool that can replicate to Azure SQL